# Remapping L390 Japanese keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint

currently I am owning a Thinkpad L390 from japan, which have a japanese keyboard layout. I am trying to fix this problem by re mapping the 5 additional keys, how can I do this on Linux Mint??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.